# How to display multiple drawables (with margins) inside ImageView programatically

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, android-drawable

Is it possible to show multiple drawables (with margins in between them) inside an ImageView without using a frame layout + any unnecessary nesting? How can following be achieved?

1. Each drawable to appear as normal without any resizing
2. Only `drawableA` and `drawableB` to have 10dp margin on the end/right

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
        Resources r = getContext().getResources();
        int tenDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, r.getDisplayMetrics());

        ImageView customIV = content.findViewById(R.id.myImgView);
        Drawable drawableA = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_happyface);
        Drawable drawableB = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_neutralface);
        Drawable drawableC = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sadface);
        customIV.addView(?);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ImageView` only houses a single `Drawable`. Multiple `ImageViews` are needed to display multiple `Drawable`s.

You could replace the root `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` to avoid nesting.